# Where to put business logic in simulation scenario?

Tags: java, oop

I have several operators in a simulation setting.
An operator has a location, a target location, a task and some status information (e.g. energy level).
The simulation should perform simulation steps and set the operators' target location.
At each simulation step, the operator should move towards his target location, update his status information and may change his task.

Now I wonder where to put these update logic.
Should I use a service class which manipulates the operator's status or put a `makeSimulationStep()` method in the operator class?
On the one hand, the first approach is somehow an anemic domain model, but on the other hand the second approach seems as it puts simulation related tasks in the operator class.

Answer (score 0):

This seems more like game logic, but I would go with the Operator class providing information about the Operator making a simulation step, and assemble this information in an Animation class.

Something like this:

```
while (inAnimationLoop) {    
    for (Operator operator : operators) {
        operator.updateSimulation();
        operator.drawPosition();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, game logic might be a more appropriate term. The tool will be used for controlled experiments on monitoring tasks. However, I think the `drawPosition()` method violates the separation between model and gui. I will use observer pattern for this.